# Why does the filter function return an empty array?

Tags: javascript

Why my filter function returns empty in `javascript`

```
const result = [{"name": "josh", ...},{"name": "mike", ...},{"name": "john", ...},{"name": "simmon", ...}]
const data = 'j'
const title = result.filter(x => x.name=== data )
```

It should return this

```
const result = [{"name": "josh", ...},{"name": "john", ...}]
```

Comment: Try `x.name.startsWith(data)`

Comment: the triple equal check for complete match. if you want to partial match you can use includes() function. like `x.name.includes(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if name is equal to j and therefore the filter is working as expected.

Try to use startsWith

```
const result = [{"name": "josh", ...},{"name": "mike", ...},{"name": "john", ...},{"name": "simmon", ...}]
const data = 'j'
const title = result.filter(x => x.name.startsWith(data) )
```